# how to split an array by value

Tags: python, numpy

My code so far is:

```
import numpy as np
data=np.genfromtxt('filename')
print(data)
```

which prints:

```
[[ 0.723  1.   ]
 [ 0.433  2.   ]
 [ 0.258  1.   ]
 [ 1.52   2.   ]
 [ 0.083  2.   ]
 [ 2.025  1.   ]
 [ 3.928  1.   ]]
```

How do i split the data into two groups, based on if the line has a 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use `np.where` which returns results of a conditional statement in the form of a tuple of arrays, which can be directly used with numpy's advanced slice notation to slice that data into a new variable.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
[[ 0.723,  1.   ],
 [ 0.433,  2.   ],
 [ 0.258,  1.   ],
 [ 1.52,   2.   ],
 [ 0.083,  2.   ],
 [ 2.025,  1.   ],
 [ 3.928,  1.   ]])

data1 = data[np.where(data[:,1] == 1)]
data2 = data[np.where(data[:,1] == 2)]

print(data1)
print(data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.asarray([[0.723, 1.],
                   [0.433, 2.],
                   [0.258, 1.],
                   [1.520, 2.],
                   [0.083, 2.],
                   [2.025, 1.],
                   [3.928, 1.]])
split_data = [data[data[:,1] == 1.], data[data[:,1] == 2.]]
print(f'data:\n{data}')
print(f'split_data:\n{split_data}')
```

**Explanation:**

`data[:,1]` references the value in the 2nd "column" per se.

**Output:**

```
data:
[[0.723 1.   ]
 [0.433 2.   ]
 [0.258 1.   ]
 [1.52  2.   ]
 [0.083 2.   ]
 [2.025 1.   ]
 [3.928 1.   ]]
split_data:
[array([[0.723, 1.   ],
        [0.258, 1.   ],
        [2.025, 1.   ],
        [3.928, 1.   ]]), 
 array([[0.433, 2.   ],
        [1.52 , 2.   ],
        [0.083, 2.   ]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was rather brief, so I didn't quite catch the dataformat but I tried replicating it with:

```
foo = [[ 0.723,  1   ], [ 0.433,  2   ], [ 0.258,  1   ], [ 1.52,   2   ],
       [ 0.083,  2   ], [ 2.025,  1   ], [ 3.928,  1   ]]
```

In case would want to filter this list `foo` to only contain numbers matching certain number you could use the following list comprehension:

```
foo_is_1 = [e for e in foo if e[1] == 1]
foo_is_2 = [e for e in foo if e[1] == 2]
print(foo_is_1)
print(foo_is_2)
```

In case you know nothing about the second argument and just want to split your list up in a list of lists with unique second arguments you could use:

```
list_of_lists = [[e for e in foo if e[1] == a] for a in list(set([a[1] for a in foo]))]
for entry in list_of_lists:
    print(entry)
```

Which is basically two list comprehensions, one for each unique second argument `a`, and one for each entry `e` in `foo`.